# How to count total records read in source using Flink dataset API

Tags: apache-flink

We currently use Flink DataSet API to do read files from FileSystem and apply some batch transformations. We also want to obtain the total records processed after when the job is finished. 
The pipeline is like `dataset.map().filter()`

count() function seems to be a non-parallel operator and it needs an extra computation from the all dataset.

Is there any approaches to count processed records in the map operator and give a side output like streaming so we can aggregate them to get the total count? Or any other better way to do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951458/flink-dataset-count-is-bottleneck-how-to-count-parallel

Comment: It seems that I need extra operators to do the count which means I have to iterator the dataset twice to get both original result and count. Is there any approaches to integrate the count logic into map/flatmap operator and produce another dataset<Long> to do count?

Comment: I think this thread really answers the question ;) The idea is that You need to have partial counts on one machine to be able to do the final count. So, You need something like counting values per key and then calculate the overall count of all of them on one machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [`counters`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/api_concepts.html#accumulators--counters). These counters allow you to output small statistics for each task that get accumulated automatically when the job finishes.

Comment: Hi, how to get the counter result in a detached yarn flink job?

Comment: Counters are usually evaluated in your driver program (the `main` that calls `execute`). You can then post the results in any way you want, once `execute` finishes.

Comment: It seems only work with attached mode submission. If a submit a job to yarn in detached mdoe. The client program end after I called execute() and I cannot get any submission result.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't think of the client being outside the cluster. In general, in detach mode, you cannot perform meaningful stuff in the client after `execute` except you wait for the results, which defeats the purpose of detached execution. I'll update my answer with some alternatives.